# Why does this choose statement not work in an Access criteria?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I really don't know what I did wrong...I was following advice from a blog post stating that this code would allow me to keep Access from breaking up my criteria (I have a ton of criteria and it was making this statement into four separate lines and adding columns.) Here's my code right now.

```
Choose(1,(([dbo_customerQuery].[store])>=[forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreFrom] Or 
[forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreFrom] Is Null) And (([dbo_customerQuery].[store])
<=[forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreTo] Or [forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreTo] 
Is Null))
```

The statement inside of the choose is definitely correct so am I using "Choose" wrong? I don't get it, the blog post used it exactly this way. When I execute queries, no matter what those fields do, I end up getting no results. The query is supposed to filter based on a date range, taking null values into account

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the query this part of? The fact you have a integer (1) as the first parameter to the Choose looks odd,  (normally this would be a variable/parameter) so this may be a fudge for something in the rest of the query

Comment: Im using the query builder, and that's the entire statement I've stuck in the "Criteria" field. That is the whole criteria, filtering from the store field. The reason I have 1 as the first parameter is based on information I read in a blog post. Access will split up the query and make it very complicated, by making the criteria take up like 4 lines. I have way too many fields to do this, as when I do this in more than one it'll become insane. The Choose statement is supposed to just automatically pick my actual statement, but trick Access into not splitting it up.

Comment: Ok, I understand the fudge now. The 'dbo_customerQuery' must be the same name as the query, is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what it was now. My statement

```
Choose(1,(([dbo_customerQuery].[store])>=[forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreFrom] Or 
[forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreFrom] Is Null) And (([dbo_customerQuery].[store])
<=[forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreTo] Or [forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreTo] 
Is Null))
```

was correct, the problem was I assumed it would work as a criteria, but it actually had to be done exactly as in the blog post posted above. It had to be posted directly as the FIELD, with "<> False" being the criteria.

Once done, it did stay on one line, and it worked just as expected.

Answer (score 1):

My concern is that you are trying to work around a bad design.  You may get this immediate issue solved to some degree, and continue to build the bad design.  Access is flexible, and forgiving, but there's a big price eventually -- maybe you're already there.

I realize this is not an answer.  It may seem rude -- I apologize.  But I think the general advice may help you.  I'll tag this "community wiki" since I'm not contributing to a programming solution.

Comment: I have a lot of respect for the source of your work-around, though -- it appears to be http://www.blueclaw-db.com/accessquerysql/too_complex.htm.

Comment: Yes, that is the source of my work-around, and the exact problem I was trying to prevent (the picture of all those lines of criteria), but I see your point. It was just that I am going to have a lot of these (Because I'm getting the query criteria from a form) and so if it got to that point it seemed like editing the criteria would be a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the placing of the parens, try this:

```
Choose(1,(([dbo_customerQuery].[store]>=[forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreFrom]) Or 
[forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreFrom] Is Null) And (([dbo_customerQuery].[store]
<=[forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreTo]) Or [forms]![TransactionsForm]![txtStoreTo] 
Is Null))
```

I have moved two closing parentheses.